# Autowire in class mentioned in bootstrap

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

When the application starts EncryptionBootstrapConfiguration is not able to Autowire my custom TextEncryptor - 
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/blob/cde7c7f3118382490c28776f66e0a56f248141fd/spring-cloud-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/bootstrap/encrypt/EncryptionBootstrapConfiguration.java

How can I ensure that this class Autowires my implementation of TextEncryptor.

Also, META-INF/spring.factories this class is mentioned as boostrap, how can i override that behavior?

My Spring-Boot Config Server -

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigServer
public class App 
{


    public static void main( String[] args )
    {

        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }

}
```

and application.yml

```
server:
  port: 8760
  ssl:
    key-store: //path
    key-store-password: '{cipher}abc'
    key-store-type: jks
    key-password: '{cipher}abc'
```

As soon it finds {cipher} it fails with FailFastTextEncryptor.

Answer (score 0):

In order for you TextEncrytor to be autowired it

- has to implement [TextEncryptor](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.8.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/crypto/encrypt/TextEncryptor.html) interface
- has to be available as bean either explicitly in configuration or with annotation (e.g. `Component`)

Comment: Sorry it got posted somehow. I already have protected static class MyTextEncryptor implements TextEncryptor with @Component and it works when the config server starts. Problem is getting it inject in this class.

Comment: The class should be public. ApplicationContext does not have access to beans with protected modifier.

Comment: Observed no difference, changed to - public class MyEncryptor implements TextEncryptor with @Component annotation but still encryptor is null in EncryptionBootstrapConfiguration.java. Edited question and added simple code

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?